# What do Groovy assertions look like with parentheses?

Tags: groovy

The example on [this page](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/GROOVY/Introduce+Assertion) only shows Groovy assertions without parentheses.

```
assert a != null, 'First parameter must not be null'
```

What would this look like if I wanted to include the parentheses? I presume that this is the closest equivalent to Perl's die() function (print error message and exit in one statement)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is:

```
assert(a != null), "First parameter must not be null"
```